# Creating a custom formula with array having multiple arguments in columns with different data

Tags: google-apps-script

Up to this point I've managed to get it to work for a single argument (`body`) but without the second argument (`photoUrl`):

```
function SendTelegram(body,photoUrl) {
  if (body.map) {
    var response = body.map(function(b) {return SendTelegram(b);});
  } else {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + 'AAA' + 
        "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(body) + 
          "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(photoUrl) + 
            "&chat_id=" + 'BBB' + 
              "&disable_web_page_preview=true&parse_mode=HTML"
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not able to understand how I should proceed to work with this two different arguments, for example, the function in the spreadsheet would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SendTelegram(A1:A,B1:B))
```

In my attempts when I try to add the second argument, it always uses the first row value in all calls, it doesn't follow the array one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, at `SendTelegram(b)` of `var response = body.map(function(b) {return SendTelegram(b);});`, the 2nd argument is not set. By this, at 2nd loop, `photoUrl` is not declared. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

And, in your script, I thought that it might be required to return the response value. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function SendTelegram(body, photoUrl) {
  if (body.map) {
    return body.map((b, i) => SendTelegram(b, photoUrl[i]));
  } else if (body && photoUrl) {
    return UrlFetchApp.fetch(
      "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + 'AAA' +
      "/sendPhoto?caption=" + encodeURIComponent(body) +
      "&photo=" + encodeURIComponent(photoUrl) +
      "&chat_id=" + 'BBB' +
      "&disable_web_page_preview=true&parse_mode=HTML", { muteHttpExceptions: true }
    ).getContentText();
  }
  return null;
}
```

#### Note:

- This is a simple modification. Because I cannot understand your expected value from the URL. So, please modify the script for your situation.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike When called, it sends the text and image to a channel alert on Telegram, the direct use is for that, I end up not needing to register anything, I just send it and finish using the function. Thanks for support!

Comment: @Brondby IF Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.